# Mongodb Read Preference Modes NEAREST but only secondary members

Tags: java, mongodb

Is there any way to specify read preference mode to nearest but only secondary members? We are running into two different data centers and our master is one of the center while secondary nodes are in both data centers. We want to save our network latency for our read operations via routing query to nearest available node but at the same time we don't our master to server high read traffic also. So I just wonder that is there any configuration available to tackle this problem ?
BTW we are using `mongo-java-driver-3.1.0.jar` Java driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but there is no "nearest but not primary" read preference. However, you can achieve the effect you want by tagging your replica set members and specifying tags in your read operations. This will limit the members used to satisfy the read to those matching the tag you specify.

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#tag-sets for details.